# how to select all of duplicate record in mysql

Tags: mysql

My records is:

```
name    |   id  |   AVG(point) as point
a       |   1   |   6
b       |   2   |   6
c       |   3   |   5
d       |   4   |   5
e       |   5   |   4
f       |   6   |   3
g       |   7   |   2
```

How to select record below:

1.I want to select top 3 record, result follow:

```
name    |   id  |   AVG(point) as point
a       |   1   |   6
b       |   2   |   6
c       |   3   |   5
d       |   4   |   5
e       |   5   |   4
```

2.I want to select record not into top 3, result follow:

```
name    |   id  |   AVG(point) as point
f       |   6   |   3
g       |   7   |   2
```

How can I do?

Comment: What have you tried? Don't expect to post your homework here and have someone answer it for you. You should google first to solve simple problems like this.

Comment: not exactly.It's not homework.My query quite complex.This post is simple result for suggest from someone.In addition, in sql server I can solve problems with `select top`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do these.  Here's a couple using `in` and `not in`.

For the top 3, you can use `in`:

```
select * 
from yourtable 
where point in (select distinct point 
                from yourtable 
                order by 1 desc 
                limit 3)
```

For the rest, use `not in` instead:

```
select * 
from yourtable 
where point not in (select distinct point 
                from yourtable 
                order by 1 desc 
                limit 3)
```

Other methods include `exists` with `not exists` and `distinct` with `joins`.

Comment: I has tried, but the query return error: `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

Comment: Sounds like you need a newer version of MySQL. Have you tried updating?

Comment: The problem is my host using version 5.6, me too. @MatthewCliatt

Comment: Do you have to use one statement? or you can use a stored procedure?

Comment: I think using stored procedure not best way in this case.Otherway, I will try using loop and test in next time. @Peter

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from yourtable as t1
inner join (select distinct point 
                from yourtable 
                order by 1 desc 
                limit 3) as t2
on t1.point = t2.point
```

For the second part of your question, do not use

```
desc
```